# "Galois subfields of real radical extensions are at most quadratic"

Tags: galois-theory

I was looking at the following page that attempts to prove that any Galois extension of a subfield $F$ of $\mathbb R$ contained in $F(\sqrt[n]{a})$ for some real $a$ with a real $n$th root must have degree at most $2$. http://planetmath.org/node/40163

I'm not sure about a step in their proof, where they conclude from $L'=F'(\sqrt[n]{\beta})$ that $L=F(\sqrt[n]{\beta})$. Is this step actually valid? If so, why? If not, how can the proof be repaired?

Comment: Rudely posted to m.se, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/835656/galois-extension-of-real-subfield-is-of-degree-at-most-2, without notice to either site.

Comment: The link to `planetmath.org` is broken. I'm also unable to find any snapshot saved on the Wayback Machine. Perhaps the content has been moved here on PlanetMath: [Galois subfields of real radical extensions are at most quadratic](https://planetmath.org/galoissubfieldsofrealradicalextensionsareatmostquadratic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $N$ be a normal closure of $K$, so $N$ is $K$ adjoin an $n$th root of unity. Then you know the Galois group of $N$ over $K$, and you know the Galois group of $N$ over $F$, and the group of $N$ over $L$ has to be a normal subgroup of the group of $N$ over $F$, containing the group of $N$ over $K$. A little group theory should finish things off.